# Exception when deserializing nhibernate object

Tags: wpf, nhibernate, serialization, treeview, lazy-loading

I have a module which retrieve a serialized nhibernate object from the dragged object :

```
DragObject dragObject = e.Data.GetData(typeof(DragObject)) as DragObject;
Object content = XamlServices.Load((new StringReader(dragObject.Xaml)));
```

But I get an exception in the second line saying :

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your `dragObject` is the object which is serialized with nhibernate. Apparently the `Xaml` property is lazy loaded (or accesses a lazy loaded property of the class).

You need to load the `dragObject` in the same session where you access all lazy loaded properties:

```
using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    DragObject dragObject = e.Data.GetData(typeof(DragObject)) as DragObject;
    Object content = XamlServices.Load((new StringReader(dragObject.Xaml)));
}
```

Alternatively you can also eager load the lazy properties.

Comment: Unfortunatly, The data access layer is seperate from the GUI so I can't open the session from this context.

Comment: Then you have to eager load the lazy property in the data access layer.